# How to make input field on full screan on position absolute

Tags: html, jquery, css

In header i have search field, which should have with same lice container.

Some how i need to make biger input, example:

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

My code [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/qunzorez/5svrwd72/4/)

```
$(".search-input").on("mousedown", function () {
    $(this).addClass('active');
    $('.search_container').addClass('test')
});

$(".cancel-icon").on("mousedown", function () {
    $('#search-content').hide();
    $('.search-input').removeClass('active');
    $('.search-input').val('');
    $('.search_container').removeClass('test')
});
```

For some reason input don't wanna go biger -_-

Answer (score 1):

create one more class of your name. I just call it as `.some` and it to `div.search-field` when input is active and remove it when `cancel-icon` is clicked.

```
.some{
  flex-shrink: 0;
  width: 100%;
  transition: width 1s;
}

.search-field{
  ...
  width: 50%;
  ...
}

$(".search-input").on("mousedown", function () {
    ...
    $('.search-field').addClass('some');
});

$(".cancel-icon").on("mousedown", function () {
    ...
    $('.search-field').removeClass('some');
});
```

`display: flex` making the `.search-field` shrink. In order to avoid that I added `flex-shrink: 0`

**Updated**
Added `transition: width 1s` to animate a width of `.search-field` and added an extra style `width: 50%` to an existing `.search-field` which doesn't change the existing size but it will make impact in transition.

Comment: Good solution, but animation is not working :(

Comment: @Andrew Updated the answer. I know `width: 50%` is not a good idea but it works fine without making any conflicts..